# Merging Two Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, each with some columns that are the same. However, each table also contains data that is unique. (Similar data includes a row name).

What I need to do is tack on the data from table two to it's matching row in table one (matching the name column).

Is there any way to do this?

I need stuff from table two to go into table 1 where the names match:

[image: An ERD]

Comment: when you say tack on are you talking about having it in the same row or different rows? Also when you say that the data is unique are the datatypes different?

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear. The rows match, and I simply want to add the columns from table 2 onto the matching row of table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should return all matching rows with columns from both tables. Note that any unique rows (that only exist in table one or two) will be excluded.

```
SELECT 
  one.matchingColum, 
  one.oddColum, 
  two.evenColumn
FROM one
JOIN two on one.matchingColumn = two.matchingColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data types are the same, then you can do a union

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

If the datatypes are not the same and you have a field that you can JOIN on, then you can do a JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```